# Spark driver logs on edge node in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, logging

I want to parse driver's log of my Spark streaming application (started in cluster mode) at runtime.

Is it possibile to force a driver to log on the edge node which I used to submit the application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the driver logs to be on the local disk from which you called `spark-submit`, then you must submit the application in client-mode.

Otherwise, a driver is ran on any possible node in the cluster.

In theory, you could couple your Spark/Hadoop/YARN logs with a solution like Fluentd or Filebeat, stream the logs into Kafka or a raw socket stream for example, then read them back into Spark, however that may be too complex for your needs.

Comment: Is possibile to parse Spark logs directly with Filebeat from HDFS?

Comment: Assuming you're concerned by your application logs (and not Spark technical logs), you can configure log4j (1.2) to send logs to Logstash  through a Socker Appender and  feed a Elasticsearch instance. Note that Elastic.co does not recommend using the LOG4J interface in latest ELK versions but that works very well, even in production.

Comment: @Harold Logback could also be used, which is preferable over log4j https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/master/README.md#udp-appender

Comment: @cricket_007 indeed, I did not know that lib. But you may not want to be dependant from any logging backend